# Does ${@:-1} really return last argument?

Tags: bash, arguments

I am running the following code when I have two arguments

```
if (( $# == 2 )); then
  : ${fdir:="${@:-1}"}
  pfm -w2 "" "unspecified -d option"
  echo "use last argument as substitute"
  printf '%s\n\n' "fdir: ${@:-1}"
  echo "\$1: $1  \$2: $2"
```

This is the result

```
pregion --dyn "John" ./01cuneus
pregion --dyn John ./01cuneus

unspecified -d option
use last argument as substitute
fdir: John

./01cuneus

$1: John  $2: ./01cuneus
```

Answer (score 6):

No, `"${@:-1}"` doesn't. But `"${@: -1}"` does.

But note that at least in Bash and Ksh, if there are no positional parameters, then `"${@: -1}"` gives `"$0"`, i.e. the shell name. This is similar to how using `${@:0}` gives `$0` and all positional the positional parameters. Zsh doesn't seem to give `$0` with `${@: -1}` or the cleaner `${@[-1]}`.

The gotcha here is that `${var:-value}` is a standard expansion which expands to the default value *value* if *var* is unset or empty. The substring/array slice expansion `${var:p:n}`, of which `${@: -1}` is a special case, is not standard and the shell interprets `${@:-1}` as the default value expansion on `$@`. The space removes the ambiguity, and so would putting the index in a variable, e.g. `i=-1; echo "${@:i}"`

```
set -- a b c        
echo "${@: -1}"       # prints 'c', the last element
echo "${@:-1}"        # prints 'a b c'

set -- 
echo "${@: -1}"       # prints '/bin/bash' or something like that
echo "${@:-1}"        # prints '1', the default value given
echo "${@:-no args}"  # prints 'no args'
```

---

Also as noted in comments, the expansion in `: ${fdir:="${@:-1}"}` is unquoted, so it may cause the shell to generate an arbitrarily long list of filenames. That could be prevented with `: "${fdir:="${@: -1}"}"`, or the perhaps more readable `[ -z "$fdir"] && fdir="${@: -1}"`

Comment: May also be worth noting that in `: ${fdir:="${@: -1}"}`, the quotes are in the wrong place as the expansion would be subject to split+glob (and even when passed to `:` constitute the kind of DoS vulnerability described at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: In `zsh` (or fish), you'd rather use `$argv[-1]`. Also `${@[-1]}` in zsh or yash.

Comment: Then it would be safer to use `${@:$#}`.

Comment: @Pietru, not sure what difference that would make. It also would give `$0` if there were no positional parameters

Comment: I meant that `"${@:$#}"` as safer option than `"${@: -1}"`, in case one misses the space.

Comment: @ilkkachu: In bash 4.1, I don’t see `"${@: -1}"` giving me `"$0"` if `$#` is zero. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … `"${@:(-1)}"` is also good if you’re concerned about losing the space to a transcription error.

Comment: @Scott, seems to happen only from Bash 4.4 onwards. I don't know why, I can't see anything matching that in the changelog. Though it says that since 4.0, `${@:0:x}` should include `$0`, but in 4.0 to 4.3, it doesn't seem to do that if there are no positional parameters at all. So perhaps that's been fixed in 4.4 and it affects `-1` also